# PyQt/PySide How to access/move QGraphicsItem after having added it to QGraphicsScene

Tags: python-3.x, pyside, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

This might be a very uninformed question.

I've been trying to figure out `QGraphics*`, and have run into a problem when trying to move an item (a pixmap) relative to or inside of the `QGraphicsView`.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow,myProgram.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)

        pic = QPixmap('myPic.png')

        self.scene.addPixmap(pic)

        print(self.scene.items())
```

This is the relevant part of the program with an arbitrary PNG

[image]

My goal, for example, would be to move the trash-can to the left-most part of the `QGraphicsView`.

I tried appending this to the code above:

```
   pics = self.scene.items()
    for i in pics:
        i.setPos(100,100)
```

However, it doesn't make a difference, and even if it did, it would be awkward to have to search for it with a "for in".

So my questions are:

1. How do I access a `QPixmap` item once I have added it to a `QGraphicsView` via a `QGraphicsScene`. (I believe The `QPixmap` is at this point a `QGraphicsItem`, or more precisely a `QGraphicsPixmapItem`.)
2. Once accessed, how do I move it, or change any of its other attributes.

Would be very grateful for help, or if anyone has any good links to tutorials relevant to the question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need to set the size of your scene and then set positions of the items, check this example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui as gui

app = gui.QApplication([])

pm = gui.QPixmap("icon.png")

scene = gui.QGraphicsScene()
scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 200, 100) #set the size of the scene

view = gui.QGraphicsView()
view.setScene(scene)

item1 = scene.addPixmap(pm) #you get a reference of the item just added
item1.setPos(0,100-item1.boundingRect().height()) #now sets the position

view.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thank you!

Comment: You know what sucks is I've spent the last 20 minutes or so programming a chunk of code to demonstrate this issue so I could come on here and ask a very similar question because I was having the same issue only to find this one which solves the issue. So I'm gonna go delete all the code I made.

Thanks for the solution!!!